# Trying to implement faster System.Collection.Generic.HashSet difference for sets that typically have few differences

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, hashset, set-difference

The normal way of doing set difference without mutating an incoming set is to construct a clone of the first incoming set and remove all the items in the second incoming set using HashSet.ExceptWith. However my profiler shows a lot of time spent in expensive HashSet.Remove calls, which I would like to avoid.

I'm thinking I can use enumerators to implement a faster set difference function for sets that tend to have fewer differences like so -

```
    public static List<T> DifferenceFast<T>(this HashSet<T> set, HashSet<T> set2) where T : IEquatable<T>
    {
        var result = new List<T>();
        using (var enr = set.GetEnumerator())
        using (var enr2 = set2.GetEnumerator())
        {
            var enr2Going = enr2.MoveNext();
            while (enr.MoveNext())
            {
                if (enr2Going)
                {
                    var item = enr.Current;
                    var item2 = enr2.Current;
                    if (!Equals(item, item2) && !set.Contains(item2)) result.Add(item);
                    else enr2Going = enr2.MoveNext();
                }
                else result.Add(enr.Current);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

However there are cases where this code doesn't work.

Can someone help me improve this algorithm or let me know if the current algorithm is making invalid assumptions about order?

Comment: "However there are cases where this code doesn't work" - it would be really good if you could share such a case.

Answer (score 1):

The elements of `HashSet` are not sorted, so if the two sets are enumerated as below:

- `set`:  3 1 2
- `set2`: 1 2

when you compare 3 (from `set`) and 1 (from `set2`), they are not the same, but `set` contains 1.

Then `enr2` and `enr` will both move to the next item: the 3 (from `set`) is skipped and won't be added into the result.

Maybe you can use `HashSet<T>.SymmetricExcept`, it's convenient to achieve your purpose.